# How to check if hot standby serves read-only queries

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have setup replication: master - slave. Slave server works as hot-standby, which means we can run read-only sql queries.
How actually can I see that slave server is serving read-only queries?

Comment: You can see it by running a query (on the slave).

Answer (score 27):

You can use `pg_is_in_recovery()` which returns `True` if recovery is still in progress(so the server is running in standby mode). Check the [System Administration Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-admin.html) for further informations.

```
=# SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery
───────────────────
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Well, actually I want to know does standby server executes sql queries. For example, on master I can run `SELECT datname, query FROM pg_stat_activity ;` and see what live queries are there. On slave/standby I can only see current query (from pg_stat_activity)

Comment: If I execute a read-only query on the master server, is it automatically dispatched to the slave server?

Comment: @DarionBadlydone No, you need to route your read-only query to slave server, by configuring your application or by using proxy software.

Answer (score 0):

You can see simply with linux `top` command with pressing `c`. For example it is a process from our standby site `top` command list

```
postgres: pgUserNameSeen pgDatabaseName 10.10.10.10 (56608) idle
```

if you do not see anything like that, your standby does not server for `read-only` queries.